# Zip line support

Tags: wood

I installed a zip line for my 7 YO grandson and his friends.  The yard had good trees to pick from on one end, but not the other.  The house has a walk-out basement with deck from the main floor.  I attached a 6 foot length of treated 4x4 to the double 2x12 structural member of the deck, so that the 4x4 would be perpendicular to the zip line route.  I attached the zip line near one end.  The configuration amounted to an overhung load on the 4x4.  It worked OK for the kids, but an adult sat on the seat to illustrate a concern she had about the zip line, and the 4x4 broke.  I had previously said load limit was 90 lbs, but I was just estimating.  How many pounds of "pull" should a piece of 4x4 lumber hold, given a 3 foot overhung load?  (The 4x4 I used was treated and had been salvaged from another use.  We can/should start with a piece of new lumber.)

Comment: If it wasn't safe for a 160lb adult to sit on, then it definitely wasn't safe for a 90 pound kid to zip on. Good thing it broke then.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all surprising to me that the 4x4 "mast" broke as you describe. The geometry of a zip line is such that the tension on the line is many times greater than the weight of the rider.

One [secondary source](http://www.buildazipline.com/design.html) suggests installing the cable such that the sag is 5% of the span. If this guideline is followed, the weight of the rider creates a pulling force at each cable support of 5 times the riders weight. The support also needs to take the load created by the cable itself, which is also a multiple of the weight of the cable.

Apparently the Association for Challenge Course Technology (ACCT) and the Professional Ropes Course Association (PRCA) both publish standards on zip line design and installation, which should be considered the authority on such matters.

DISCLAIMER Everything that follows is illustrative only, the above references should be consulted before building a zip line.

**So now to attempt to answer your question:** How many pounds of "pull" should a piece of 4x4 lumber hold, given a load applied 3 feet from the support point?

You've essentially got what's called a cantilever beam. In a cantilever beam you have both bending and shear stresses to consider, though in this case the bending stresses are the primary concern.

A #2 southern pine 4x4 post has a maximum allowable fiber stress of [850psi](http://www.forestryforum.com/members/donp/Fblist.htm).

For a simple beam of square cross-section

`Max bending stress = 6*M/(b^3)`

where M is the bending moment (load in the cable (P) times the overhang of 36 inches)
and b is the length of a side of the square (3.5 inches for a 4x4)

Rearranging a bit to solve for the max "pull":

`P=(b^3*max allowable stress)/(6*length of overhang)`

`P=(3.5in)^3*850psi/(6*36in)=168lb`

So the post can withstand about 168 lb of pull from the cable (really it should be a little bit less when the shear forces are also considered).

**But as I stated earlier, the tension in the cable can be around 5 times the weight of the person hanging from the zip line,** so the max "safe" weight with this back-of-envelope calculation is only around `168lb/5=34lb`, even before applying a typical factor-of-safety to the calculations to account for the dynamic nature of the load, and the fact that a person's (relative) safety depends on it.

So based on these calculations, even with just kids on the zip line, you were very near, if not exceeding the design load limits for your 4x4 post.

With a 3 foot overhang, a 4x4 post is nowhere near strong enough to safely support a zip line, even for kids.